# Weird PHP Encoding code. Any reason?

Tags: php, post

I was going through some "legacy" code and found something that I don't quite understand. Here is the code :

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$name = htmlspecialchars_decode($name);
$name = addslashes($name);
$name = htmlentities($name, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$name = html_entity_decode($name);

InsertIntoDatabase($name); //SQL server
```

I understand every single line individually but my question is :

**Why did the programmer do all that?**

At first, all this code seems useless. `htmlentities` and `html_entity_decode` nullify each other, `htmlspecialchars_decode` seems useless and `addslashes` actually inserts garbage in our database by adding `\` before every `'`;

So, I feel like removing it all but it bugs me that the previous developer went to the trouble of adding that construction everywhere in the code base. He must had a good reason. Right?

We are (still) using php 5.3. Any clue why he did all that?

Comment: The only thing i can guess at is that he wanted compatability with some other language in which he then wouldnt have to add \ as escape characters but even then it seems really wastefull...

Comment: Without context we can't know what the programmer was thinking. If this is indeed just a way to clean up a variable so it can go in the database then it's just garbage. However you'd need to go through your database and reverse all of if if you are to remove this. Maybe it was left alone because of people being unwilling to dedicate time and energy to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really overkill, only `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` would be usefull here if you wish to remove HTML characters

You should however still see how are these values stored and used in your database because adding slashes was an old way to specify escape characters

Comment: The weird part is that he started with htmlspecialchars_decode instead of htmlspecialchars.

Comment: Well , I can't explain why with that much background you provided